# datetime microseconds not exported in django dumpdata

Tags: django

When I use the django dumpdata command, all my timestamps (originating as DateTImeField objects in my models) are represented as a string such as "2010-11-25 07:07:12", with no microseconds.  When I examine the same object via the shell I see something like datetime.datetime(2010, 11, 25, 7, 7, 12, 739842), with microsecond granularity.

Why doesn't dumpdata export the microseconds, and is there a simple workaround?

Answer (score 1):

That's a great question, and even one of the founders of Django admit that they don't know why they did remove that information: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10201

Should be a matter of copying the built-in serializer and changing a couple of lines to include the microsecond information.